# TypeError: Object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a code below:

```
var FilledObjectArray = function() {
    this.filledObject = {};
};

FilledObjectArray.prototype = {
        fill: function() {
            this.filledObject["one"] = 1;
        }
};

var SomeClass = function() {
    this.something = new FilledObjectArray();
};

SomeClass.prototype = {
    showContents: function() {
        this.something.fill();
        for (key in this.something) {
            $("#some-div").append(this.something[key]);
        }
    }   
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    var s = new SomeClass();

    $(".bla").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            s.showContents();
        });
    });

});
```

I'm getting this error in Firebug console:

```
TypeError: this.filledObject is undefined
this.filledObject["one"] = 1;
```

What I'm doing wrong here? From what I understand object is properly initialized and value assigning is correct. I'm testing this in Firefox 18.0.2 version and Chrome 25.

Comment: I think that this. in this.filledObject["one"] = 1; refers to the closure and not to the FilledObjectArray

Comment: Is this an instance where its worth while creating a `self` reference to avoid confusion about what `this` is at any given point?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the error? I don't get an exception when executing `s.showContents()` - I only can spot the inconsistency that Kevin detected (yet that would lead to another error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit dumb right now but here is the solution to this:

```
SomeClass.prototype = {
    showContents: function() {
        this.something.fill();
        for (key in this.something.filledObject) {
            if (this.something.filledObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                $("#some-div").append(this.something.filledObject[key]);                
            }
        }
    }   
};
```

I was trying to access object itself (this.something) instead of object property (this.something.filledObject)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem

```
this.something.fill.call(this.something);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue with the existing code and have created a proposed solution, however I'm not exactly clear on your intent so it may be a little different than your needs, please modify as needed.

**The Issue**

The main issue stems from the `FilledObjectArray` object.  This object's prototype is assigned a function `fill` and then assigned a property `one` of type int with a value of 1.  So remember this object has two properties, one a function one an int.

So when you execute this code...

```
for (key in this.something) {
    $("#some-div").append(this.something[key]);  //Item 1
}
```

Two iterations of the loop occur, once for the function `fill` and once for the property `one`.  The issue occurs on the iteration for the `fill` key, since `this.something[key]` is passed to the `append()`, which cann accept functions, causing jQuery to trigger the function.  When this occurs, within the execution context of the `fill` function, `this` is assigned to `#some-div`, which does not have a `filledObject` property, causing the TypeError to be thrown.  I have commented on some of this below:

```
var FilledObjectArray = function() {
    this.filledObject = {}; //Fill is an object
};

FilledObjectArray.prototype = {
        fill: function() {
            this.filledObject["one"] = 1;
        }
};

var SomeClass = function() {
    this.something = new FilledObjectArray();
};

SomeClass.prototype = {
    showContents: function() {
        this.something.fill();
        for (key in this.something) {
            $("#some-div").append(this.something[key]);  //The fill function is called here
        }
    }   
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    var s = new SomeClass();

    $(".bla").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            s.showContents();
        });
    });

});
```

**Proposed Solution**

```
var FilledObjectArray = function() {
    this.filledObject = [];
};

FilledObjectArray.prototype.fill = function(){
            console.log(this);
            this.filledObject[0] = 1;
};

var SomeClass = function() {
    this.something = new FilledObjectArray();
};

SomeClass.prototype = {
    showContents: function() {
        this.something.fill();
        for (var x = 0; x < this.something.filledObject.length; x++){
            $("#some-div").append(this.something.filledObject[x]);
        }
    }   
};

$(document).ready(function() {


    var s = new SomeClass();
    $(".bla").each(function() {

        $(this).click(function() {
            s.showContents();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for conceptually right, yet the enumerated property of `this.something` is `filledObject` not `one`.

Comment: Your solution works fine but I really need associative array for this.

Answer (score 0):

i think you looking for this:

```
for (key in this.something) {
  if(this.something.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    $("#some-div").append(JSON.stringify(this.something[key]));
  }
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eciwor/1)

you need use `hasOwnProperty` to iterate over the properties of an object without executing on inherit properties.