# How can I get my images to show up on the main display of the page?

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is Use the NASA API to receive some photos. and then display those photos on the thumbnails and main display of my web page.

I just can figure out why the code doesn't take the images from the thumbnails and display them on the page. I'm also using a template site from HTML5 up. I'm not all too familiar with the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

So the way the site seems to be working is that it takes the image src and the a tag href value to display them in the thumbnail and main display. I'm using the fetch request to get the NASA API information. Im then overwriting the HTML code by using the data.map method and inserting my own HTML.

My thought was that if I overwrote the previous HTML with the one in the fetch request it would work fine. but it's not.

Also attaching a replit link to see the whole site in real time: https://replit.com/@jamesYamez/nasa-api#nasa-api-site/index.html

I think the main error is

> Uncaught TypeError: newSlide is undefined

```
fetch(url)
    .then(req => req.json())
    .then((data)=> {
        //using map to assign the data values to the html
    let html = data.map(item => `
        <article>
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="${item.hdurl}" data-position="left center"      target="_blank"><img src="${item.url}" alt="..." /></a>
            <h2>${item.title}</h2>
            <p>${item.explanation}</p>
        </article>
        `)
        thumbnails.innerHTML = html.join("")
    })
    .catch((e) => console.error(e))
```

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109565/typeerror-object-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code but your css/style need to resize images adequately

```
<body >
        <!--display fetched user data -->
    <div id="NASA">


    </div>
    
<script>
    url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&count=2"
  
// 1. GET request using fetch()
  fetch(url)
    .then((req) => req.json())
    .then((data) => {
        let html;
// 2. Loop through each data
        data.forEach((data) => {

             html += `
        <article>
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="${data.hdurl}" data-position="left center"      target="_blank"><img src="${data.url}" alt="..." /></a>
            <h2>${data.title}</h2>
            <p>${data.explanation}</p>
        </article>
        `
// 3. DOM Display result
        document.getElementById("NASA").innerHTML = html;

    });
});

</script>
</body>
```

Edit: Open image in the same page using modal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body >

        <!--display fetched user data -->
        <div id="NASA">


        </div>
    
<script>
    url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&count=3"
  
    // 1. GET request using fetch()
  fetch(url)
  //Converting received data to JSON
    .then((req) => req.json())
    .then((data) => {
          // 2. Create a variable to store HTML table headers
    let html = ``;
    // 3. Loop through each data
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach((data) => {

            html += `
        <article>
                        <img data-enlargeable src="${data.url}" alt="..." />
            <h2>${data.title}</h2>
            <p>${data.explanation}</p>
        </article>
        `;

    });
    // 4. DOM Display result
    document.getElementById("NASA").innerHTML= html;


//JQUERY create a modal clickable to expand image
    $('img[data-enlargeable]').addClass('img-enlargeable').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  var modal;

  function removeModal() {
    modal.remove();
    $('body').off('keyup.modal-close');
  }
  modal = $('<div>').css({
    background: 'RGBA(0,0,0,1) url(' + src + ') no-repeat center',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: '10000',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    cursor: 'zoom-out'
  }).click(function() {
    removeModal();
  }).appendTo('body');
  //handling ESC
  $('body').on('keyup.modal-close', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
      removeModal();
    }
  });
});

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you writing this inside the html or javascript?

Comment: all is inside html body (script use javascript)  ---------


 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

HERE

</body>
</html>

Comment: Hi Claudio Gutierrez. So i tried it, but its not working. did you get it to work. the thumbnails are showing up fine. that was never an issue. the issue is that the images are not showing up in the main display. What is suppose to happen is i click an image and it shows on the main display. did your code work? thanks for helping

Comment: I did an edit with: Open image in the same page using modal i'm not sure if that is what you want my english can be bad sometimes haha

Comment: hey man thanks for trying but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to replace the image with the hd version, you just need to update the `src` attribute.

```js
const url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&count=3"

fetch(url)
  .then(req => req.json())
  .then((data) => {
    let html = ''
    data.forEach(item => html += `
        <article>
            <img src="${item.url}" alt="${item.title}"  data-hdurl="${item.hdurl}" />
            <h2>${item.title}</h2>
            <p>${item.explanation}</p>
        </article>
        `)
    document.querySelector("#NASA").innerHTML = html
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error(e))

document.querySelector('#NASA').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const data = e.target.dataset
  if ('hdurl' in data) {
    console.log(`loading ${data.hdurl}`)
    e.target.src = data.hdurl
    delete data.hdurl
  }
})
```

```css
#NASA img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

[data-hdurl] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="NASA"></div>
```